# Editing Resource files in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

Is there a way to modify the Resource files for my ASP.NET Core application by code?

I tried to find the `System.Resources.ResourceWriter` but such a class does not exist, there is only `System.Resources.ResourceReader`..., and in order to use the `ResXResourceWriter` class I need to add the `System.Windows.Forms.dll`?!

I would like that strings in my WebApp be editable, admin users to be allowed to modify messages and GUI element texts...

Comment: You need the [System.Resources.Writer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Resources.Writer/) nuget package.

Comment: oh, great... just has no `ResourceWriter(string filename)` constructor... )

Comment: Dunno what you are doing, but for me it has a string and Stream constructor. And even w/o a string constructor you can still use the stream constructor. `new ResourceWriter(new StreamWriter(@"C:\somepath\res.xml")`, second this likely wouldn't even work for you, because once the resource files are loaded you can't unload them w/o restarting the application. And why do you even use resource files and not read them from database or an xml file in the first place? https://damienbod.com/2015/10/21/asp-net-5-mvc-6-localization/ It's old but still applicable